# setState(…): Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the code. No idea as to why there is a problem.

```
class TeacherForm extends Component {
  constructor({ data }) {
    super();

    this.isUpdatingForm = !! data;
    this.state = Object.assign({ ... });

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.removeTeacher = this.removeTeacher.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(value, field) {
    this.setState({ shouldUpdate: true, [field]: value });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, subjects, parttime, timing } = this.state;

    if (this.isUpdatingForm) {
      return update.call({
        _id: this.props.data._id,
        transaction: { name, subjects, parttime, timing },
      }, () => this.setState({ shouldUpdate: false }));
    }

    return add.call();
  }

  removeTeacher() {
    return remove.call(this.props.data._id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
         ...
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

The error gets thrown at the handleSubmit method in the callback of `update.call`. This normally shows up when I call `removeTeacher` and a list updates and this component unmounts.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the callback `() => this.setState({ shouldUpdate: false })` is executed after that the component is unmounted. Is that possible? If so, one way to get around that is to replace this part by

```
return update.call({
  _id: this.props.data._id,
  transaction: { name, subjects, parttime, timing },
}, () => { !this.unmounted && this.setState({ shouldUpdate: false }); });
```

and to add

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.unmounted = true;
}
```

Comment: It should run on form submit. Is there any reason as to why it may run after being unmounted. If it is unmounted, the form never gets submitted so should technically not run.

Comment: Update.call is called synchronously when the component is mounted. But it looks like the callback that changes the state can fire after that the component is unmounted

Comment: You can add a logs in 1) Handle submit just before update.call, 2) in the callback 3) in componentWillUnmount and see in which order they got called